# How to create and bind on vmodel of a button

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

`i am using vue3 with options api`

as shown in the code posted below, i know how create a radio-button and how to bind on its properties. But my question is how to bind on properties of a button.
as shown in the code posted below,i can bind on `@click` but i do not know how to create and bind on `vmodel` of the button

**radio-button**

```
<input
    type="radio"
    :value="compPropsVModelEpochAgo"
    @input="$emit('update:compPropsVModelEpochAgo', $event.target.value)"
    :disabled="isRadioButtonEpochAgoDisabled"
    :checked="isCheckedRadioButtonEpochAgo"
    @change="onEpochAgoChanged()"
/>
```

**button**

```
<cds-button 
    class="clsBtnClosePosition" 
    action="primary" 
    status="primary" 
    size="md" 
    type="button" 
    @click="onCloseNotification()"
> X
</cds-button>
```

explained in the question

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, and you don't attempt to use v-model in your code.  It sounds like you just want to add `v-model="someVariable"` to your button, so why don't you?  If you have a specific question about v-model, you may want to review the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) first.

Comment: @yoduh would you please tell me how to add v-model to a button?

Comment: The official documentation is very good and has everything you need.  On a native element there is nothing to do other than type it out `<button v-model="someVariable" />`  ... If it's for a custom component you're making, the component script code will need to be set up to accept v-model binding, which is in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html).  I can not improve on it's explanation, so please give it a read and attempt it on your own.  If you have additional questions or problems then update your question with the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

The `Vue` `v-model` creates a 2 way binding between the component and some state.  A button generates a "click" event, but what is your definition of the button's "state".

The text of the button does not need two-way binding, as the user cannot edit the text.

```
<button>{{text}}</button>
```

There is no real need to use `v-model` for an ordinary button.  The click and the text only need to be one-way bindings.  "v-model" is just shorthand for setting the ":input" and responding to some "@value" event or equivalent.

A toggle button, on the other hand would have "state", and that would use a "v-model" directive.